# Is an underline a form of punctuation?

Tags: meaning, terminology, punctuation

I was tooling around on [The Punctuation Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20190302233322/https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/index.html) when I noticed that the underscore character was not listed as a form of punctuation.

I brought this up to my friends, asking them if underscores were ever used in punctuation. One of my friends claimed that underlining a word was a usage of the underscore, and that it is a form of punctuation. The example he used was that underlines and italics are used when referencing different works, such as when citing sources.

Now, I'm pretty sure this is not a valid example, but I'm not convinced that a true counterexample doesn't exist. *Is the underscore a form of punctuation? If so, Is the example my friend gave a valid explanation? Are there any better examples out there?*

Comment: What authority would you have us cite? Unicode considers it connecting punctuation, yes.

Comment: I’d love to delete everything you people didn’t like and whether I just lack the experience, or I can’t because they’ve been moderated, I can’t…

Can you get rid of them, or what can I do, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underlining is not punctuation, but a typographical device used for emphasis:

> **Emphasis (typography)**
>
> **[Underline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_(typography))**
>
> Professional Western typesetting usually does not employ lines under
> letters for emphasis within running text, because it is considered too
> distracting. Underlining is, however, often used with typewriters, in
> handwriting and >with some non-alphabetic scripts. It is also used for
> secondary emphasis, i.e. marks added by the reader and not the author.

An underscore is a character, not punctuation. Although it is sometimes referred to as 'underline', a term dating back to when the underscore 'character' was used to underline words on typewriters. These days underscores are mostly used in passwords, e-mail addresses and the like.

> The symbol **[underscore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore)** [ _ ] (also called underline, underbar, low
> line, or low dash) is a character that originally appeared on the
> typewriter and was primarily used to underline words. To produce an
> underlined word, the word was typed, the typewriter carriage was moved
> back to the beginning of the word, and the word was overtyped with the
> underscore character.

Either way your friend was incorrect. If you are referring to the underline on a piece of work this is a typographical device of emphasis (not punctuation) and if you are referring to 'the underscore' then this is a character and also not punctuation.

Comment: I agree that the underscore is not a proper punctuation mark (in English), but punctuation marks are characters too, so that's not a good reason. -- P.S. Some would argue that in computer usage where an underscore is sometimes used as a placeholder for a space, it *is* a punctuation mark